# How to create a new file which provides filename and its source directory information

Tags: directory, solaris, mkdir

I have a directory that contains so many sub directories and files in them. I would like to create a file which provides each file name and it's source directory path information

For example:

I have a folder name sample which contains sample1 and sample2 sub directories in it.

I have `ex1.csv`, `ex2.csv` in sample 1 and `ex3.csv`, `ex4.csv` in sample 2 directory.

I need to create a text file (or) CSV file which gives the information in the following manner.

```
ex1.csv,sample/sample1
ex2.csv,sample/sample1
ex3.csv,sample/sample2
```

It would be great if someone help me out to create the script file in UNIX.

I tried: `$ find sample -type f -printf '%f,%h\n'`

As I am using Solaris it is not allowing me to use `printf` and I don't have access to install other utilities.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is compatible with your Solaris - I tested it under a SunOS 5.10 with bash 4.3.26:

```sh
find . | while read f; do
    if [ ! -d "$f" ]; then
        echo $(basename "$f"),$(dirname "$f")
    fi
done
```

This simply uses `basename` and `dirname` to split the filename.

```sh
$ find test | while read f; do if [ ! -d "$f" ]; then echo $(basename "$f"),$(dirname "$f"); fi; done
ex4,test/sample2
ex3,test/sample2
ex2,test/sample1
ex1,test/sample1
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution 

but  when i execute the following code i am getting syntax error

 `(' unexpected

Comment: Can you debug that error? Try to isolate the statement, i.e. which "(" is unexpected? What shell and version are you using?

Comment: Which shell are you using?  /bin/sh on Solaris 10 will not work with $(), as the answer specified you need to use bash for that.

Comment: GNOME Terminal 2.6.1

Comment: GNOME Terminal is a terminal emulator, not a shell. Please *first* read [Are terminal and shell the same?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/111144/are-terminal-and-shell-the-same) and [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con). *Then* answer (for yourself) the question: can you use the `bash` shell? If "yes", type `bash` in your terminal and try my solution again. If "no", we need to know which shell you use (try `echo $SHELL`).