# Solaris find doesn't support printf action

Tags: find, solaris

Can anyone provide Solaris equal command to the following command

```
$ find . -type f -printf '%f,%h\n'
```

After running the code I am getting "bad option printf find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate list error "

Printf is not supported by Solaris UNIX environment

Please refer to following links for more information:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/818478/how-to-create-a-new-file-which-provides-filename-and-its-source-directory-inform/818480

http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+sample+-type+f+-printf+%27%25f%2C%25h%5Cn%27

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `man find`.

Comment: I am new to UNIX and can you help me out on how to use man find. I cannot install any other software too

Comment: Which version of Solaris? You may have a `gfind` command.

Comment: Type the command `man find`. If you have man pages installed, it will let you read how to use the `find` command.

Comment: Did you try the alternative solution posted in answer to your earlier question [How to create a new file which provides filename and its source directory information](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306575/how-to-create-a-new-file-which-provides-filename-and-its-source-directory-inform)?

Comment: @steel Driver yes I have tried them

Comment: @Mark I have tried, there is no gfind

Answer (score 1):

The `-printf` action is specific to GNU find, so it isn't available on platforms that don't run GNU find. Only non-embedded Linux and Cygwin run GNU find unless you've installed it separately.

You can [install GNU find on Solaris](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/solaris-default-install-user-tools).

Alternatively, you can rewrite your script to use only portable features. There is no generic way to translate `-printf`: different specifiers will need different tools. For `%f` and `%h`, it's easy, since these are just parts of the file name. If the file name is in a shell variable `x`, you can use parameter expansion constructs to extract the base name (remove the prefix `*/`) and the directory name (remove the suffix `/*`).

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for x do printf %s,%s\\n "${x##*/}" "${x%/*}"; done' sh {} +
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the solution. But i am getting ; unexpected error while running the code

Comment: @vinodkumar Oh right, remove the `;` before `do`, that's a common but non-standard syntax.

Comment: Now getting find:incomplete statement error

Comment: @vinodkumar Did you copy the command exactly? Are you using some extremely ancient version of Solaris that doesn't support `-exec … {} +`? Are you calling `/usr/bin/find` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/find`?